# how to set alternative pk fonts destination on texlive

Tags: fonts, texlive, windows, paths, kpathsea

By default, TeXLive places metafont generated bitmap fonts in $TEXMFHOME: how do I change that to, say, $TEXMFVAR, without changing the whole $TEXMFHOME settings? Besides, I believe this change won't force me to run `mktexlsr` every time I generate a font, unlike setting the destination path to, say, $TEXMFTEXLOCAL; is that correct?

Comment: on my system they are put into .texlive2023/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ which is in texmfvar  according to my texmf.cnf `TEXMFVAR = ~/.texlive2023/texmf-var`.

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer but also how come you are getting enough pk files generated to make this an issue? It used to happen all the time but these days apart from the larm... cyrillic family I don't think I have seen metafont get triggered for years?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle actually my folder was empty and I had to force a generation by setting \pdfmapfile to empty ;-)

Comment: oops! on Windoze there is no $TEXMFVAR; so it looks that I may have broken something. Let me check...

Comment: does it matter where the source is? I am experimenting with a variation of a metafont, and I placed the source mf in my $TEXMFHOME tree, and the `texmf.cnf` file sets `PKFONTS = $TEXMFDOTDIR;{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/pk/{$MAKETEX_MODE,modeless}//`, so `$TEXMFDOTDIR` seems to take precedence.

Comment: Any time you modify a copy of a standard file, you should rename it. That said, yes, your current working directory will take precedence. `kpsewhich --var-value=PKFONTS` will tell you the actual value of the variable. You may have more than one `.cnf` around.

Comment: @cfr I did take all those precautions, and I still get the fonts in `$TEXMFHOME`; while `kpsewhich` reports the following: `.:{{{}/cygdrive/c/jarnosz/cyghome/.config/texmf,/cygdrive/c/jarnosz/cyghome/.cache/texmf,/cygdrive/c/Users/jarnosz/documents/256/texmf,!!/cygdrive/c/Users/jarnosz/documents/texmf-local,!!/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf-dist}/fonts,/cygdrive/c/jarnosz/cyghome/.cache/texmf/fonts}/pk/{/,modeless}//`; so the system places the fonts in the first available directory: `$TEXMFHOME` is set in cygwin to `$(cygpath $USERPROFILE)/documents/256/texmf` in `.bashrc`

Comment: Maybe ask @DavidCarlisle if it is cygwin. Setting stuff in `.bashrc` sounds wrong to me, but that a Linux perspective. Maybe there's some reason for it on cygwin, but the only thing I set in a shell config file is `PATH`. When you install TeX Live, do you get a warning about that variable? Because the Linux installer flags anything which might be TeX related in the environment as setting these kinds of things in the environment can cause problems. But, like I say, that's on Linux. David should know if that's even a thing on cygwin.

Comment: @cfr cygwin tex is pretty much identical to linux tex from a config perspective, setting things inthe environment should work in either case but you need to be careful with bashrc as it's executed for each shell so things can build up if you are not careful, setting in texmf.cnf is easier, especially if you are in the habit of launching things from a desktop that is not in an enviornment launched from your login shell

Comment: somehow `$TEXMFDOTDIR` takes precedence over anything else: and that's a Good Thing, I believe...

Comment: I tried configuring the paths via `texmf.cnf` with identical results. As @DavidCarlisle says, it does not affect my daily operations, but it is somewhat confusing that `PKFONTS` generation always points to `$TEXMFHOME`, however defined, instead of `TEXMFVAR` as, to the best of my knowledge, documented. Seemingly related to the inclusion of `TEXMFDOTDIR` in the default `texmf.cnf` configuration file.